# Does term "page" apply to a mobile app?

Tags: android, ios, terminology, mobile-application, app

I'm developing a mobile phone (iOS/Android) app and alongside that, an admin website where the app owner will update the content of the app (so basically a CMS for the app).

The app has tabs at the bottom and tapping onto them gives News, Pictures, Events calandar etc. The news contains several stories or items, so I call that the news section. But Events calandar has no sub divisions.

http://codepen.io/ionic/pen/1dcfdb07b8cc11918e65af619ad543c6 for an example of the interface

In my CMS I want to get the app owner to choose between News (item within the section), Pictures, Events calandar etc to edit their contents.

Do I say "Choose Page" as if it were a web site, or is there a more accatable term to use for a specific content item in an app?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A term that comes to mind is **panel** or **pane**, but looking at your "web application” it looks more like a website to me. The fact that it loads pages dynamically and slides them in doesn’t mean people will see it as an application, that depends more on it’s contents. So I think the term **page** will be generally understood in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I would word it as "**Choose section**", which indicates a grouping of a given content type which is likely to include "pages" in the content.

There is no hard and fast rule on this, so I would strongly suggest doing some basic UX testing with your potential customers to see which is more intuitive to them.

Comment: Hi thank you. I should have added that I am actually calling collections of "pages" sections, for example I can News a section, but that will be sub divised into stories. I'll edit the question